# Rails routing: uninitialized constant ClanController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have some problems with routing custom controller actions

Routes:

```
resources :clans do
 get 'leave' =>'clan#leave_clan'
 get 'dismiss' =>'clan#dismiss_clan'
 get 'kick_from_clan/:user_id' =>'clan#kick'
 get 'invite/:user_id' =>'clan#invite'
 get 'join' =>'clan#join'
end

namespace :admin do
 resources :clans
 resources :users
end
```

I know i have `clans` both in admin namespace and also without but that is how i need it, actions are completely different in them.

And I use a generated route as `clan_join_path(clan)`.

This action results in the next error:

```
uninitialized constant ClanController
```

Directory structure:

```
      /app
        /controller
          /admin
            /ClansController.rb
          /ClansController.rb
```

EDIT:

Also invite and kick routes are not generated as expected.

```
   *no path*  GET   /clans/:clan_id/kick_from_clan/:user_id(.:format) clan#kick
   *no path*  GET   /clans/:clan_id/invite/:user_id(.:format) clan#invite
```

Any suggestion to the edit part?

Comment: You don't have a `ClanController`.

Comment: Try `get :leave` etc. In your matching string you are using singular `clan#action`, it should be `clans#action`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining a resource called `clans` and I presume you have a controller also called `ClansController` (note the puralization). If you don't have this controller, you'll be wanting to create it.

You probably therefore need to pluralize your routes:

```
resources :clans do
 get 'leave' =>'clans#leave_clan'
 get 'dismiss' =>'clans#dismiss_clan'
 get 'kick_from_clan/:user_id' =>'clans#kick'
 get 'invite/:user_id' =>'clans#invite'
 get 'join' =>'clans#join'
end
```

Also make sure your controller is named `clans_controller.rb` (pluralized).

Comment: Oh dear, a misspelling causing a few lost hours.. Thanx for your quick answer. Would it happen for you to know what is the problem with the edited part of my question?

Comment: @LogofaT I would suggest in your case that users are a nested resource under clans, have a read of [rails routing - nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and see if this fits your scenario. (Read all of 2.7, shallow nesting should be what you want.)

Comment: Also look at [Dan's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25268028/385532), you absolutely should use member routes within your resource as he describes.

Comment: @LogofaT a member route requires an ID of a specific object and acts on that object (e.g. invite specific user to clan, kick specific user from clan). A collection route does not require an ID so can only act on any collection/objects defined in the action (e.g. show a list of clans)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `member do ... end` to properly route based on type of action

```
resources :clans do
  member do
    get :leave
    get :dismiss
    #etc
  end
end
```

This will define the routes as `clans/:id/leave` `clans/:id/dismiss`

Comment: I've linked to this from my answer as it's an important point. Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your clans_controller.rb is intentionally not plural.

```
resources :clans do
     get 'leave' =>'clans#leave_clan'
     get 'dismiss' =>'clans#dismiss_clan'
     get 'kick_from_clan/:user_id' =>'clans#kick'
     get 'invite/:user_id' =>'clans#invite'
     get 'join' =>'clans#join'
end
```

**app/controllers/clans_controller.rb**

```
class ClansController < ApplicationController

end
```